# $\log(0)$ is $-\infty$, but $\log(0)=x$ is undefined

Tags: logarithms, wolfram-alpha

In Wolfram Alpha, $log(0)$ results in $-\infty$. However, $log(0)=x$ results in undefined.

[Link to $\log(0)$ : Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(0))

[Link to $\log(0)=x$ : Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(0)%3Dx)

Shouldn't these result in the same answer?

Comment: -infity is not a number.  log 0 = -infinity means i) log 0 isn't a number and ii) as x->0 lim log x -> - infty.  log(0) = x resulting in "x is undefined" means i)log 0 insn't a number.  The terms are consistant but log(0) = -infty gives us a little more information about the behavior of log(x) and values near 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $\log(0)= -\infty$ is misleading.  Actually $\log(0)$ is undefined.  What is true is that $\lim_{x \to 0+} \log(x) = -\infty$.

Comment: Well, in Wolfram Alpha it is defined. When you claim someting is undefined, you should specify, where.

Comment: In mathematics, $\log(0)$ is undefined.  If a computer program says differently, that should be considered a bug in the program.

Comment: what is "in mathematics"? Do you have a list of definitions in mathematics and not in mathematics?

Comment: For instance, does extended real line belong to mathematics or not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Miscellaneous